# Logging User Activity

Tags: django, logging

I'm trying to store user log information. I want to do it using middleware but I couldn't able to set variable value on middleware from view. For example Activity = ['view', 'update', 'delete', 'create'] which I need to set from view. (update for database update, delete for database delete, create for database object creation). I need to log referred url, status code, user_name, datetime, client_ip and activity. Also is this the best way to store user activity log. If not then why?

Comment: Would you like to store the information in a database table? If so, maybe using the signals would be more appropriate way. Django provides already out of the box signals for all the actions you need. Hook your logic and save the needed information. It is only my opinion and the approach I would choose. More on signals in the official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: I'm using elastic search to store information...

Comment: Unfortunately I have almost no experience with elastic search, but that shouldn't be an obstacle for using signals. I must admit that my comment beginning is a little bit misleading. You can use signals without the need to store information in database. There are signals for ``save()`` (which in your case can be used for update and create) and for ``delete()``, as the names suggest for deleting database entries. Let your logic fire before or after an event using the correspondent signal.